# Add an attachment using: api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments

Tags: vba, rest, jira

I have successfully been able to create a Jira Issue, now want to to add an attachment using: api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments

My following VB code wont work, any suggestions please as this is new to me, thanks. The error I get is: HTTP Status 500 - Error parsing Content-Type

Sub JIRA_PostAttachment()

Dim pHtml As String
Dim oHttp As Object
Dim strResponse As String

pHtml = "https://jira.ae.sda.corp.test.com/rest/api/2/issue/IS-163/attachments"
sVar = """file="": ""C:\Users\c776469\FORM.msg"""

```
Set oHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Call oHttp.Open("POST", pHtml, False)
'oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;Charset=UTF-8; boundary="
'oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
oHttp.SetRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check"

oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic Yzc4NjQ3OTpHaWxpdDIwMTY/"

Call oHttp.Send(sVar)

strResponse = oHttp.ResponseText
MsgBox strResponse

Set oHttp = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this link:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39127148/answers/39127815/comments/39130956﻿

It has a VBA example that works (also a  C# example)